# ¿Cómo corrgir el error "la tokenización se omite con filas largas" en VSCode?

Tags: javascript, express, vscode

No entiendo porque esto me salio la verdad,

> Por motivos de rendimiento, la tokenización se omite con filas. Esta opción se puede configurar con "editor.maxTokenizationLineLength"

he modificado el `editor.maxTokenizationLineLength` y no lo resuelve y dejo de un dia para otro casi toda la tarea se fue a la basura, si me ayudas te lo agradeceria, aquí el error que me sale, fue abrirlo esta mañana en clase y se vio así y por poco me da algo.

El problema es que me salio lo que esta en la imagen en mi código y si hay alguna forma de solucionarlo porque no entiendo cómo me salió eso.

[image: Imagen del error]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Qué había en esa fila? Qué pusiste en el parámetro `editor.maxTokenizationLineLength`?

Comment: SI ya editaste desde max en configuracion y no resulto lei que algunos usuarios dan como solución alternar las opciones para los puntos de interrupción en las excepciones capturadas y no capturadas hace que falle